# lastpage (or pageslts) and \topskip0pt

Tags: page-breaking, lastpage, pageslts

Can anyone explain why the following mwe produces TWO pages of output?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}
\topskip 0pt
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

If I replace `\topskip 0pt` by `\topskip 1pt` (or any small non-zero positive integer), then I get the expected single page. Of course, if I don't call `lastpage`, then I also only get one page.

This happens both on MikTeX 2.9, and on a very recent version of MacTeX.

In the aux file, it says this:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{1}}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{1}
\gdef\lastpage@lastpageHy{}
```

So `LastPage` knows there should only be one page, but is somehow adding an extra one afterwards. I've found things online where `LastPage` clashes with other packages, but here it seems to be clashing with `\topskip`.

As a final comment, the same thing happens if I replace `lastpage` with `pageslts`.

Comment: As a partial answer to my own question, I probably shouldn't have `\topskip` anwhere other than the preamble. However, I still don't understand why it's causing trouble with `LastPage`...

Comment: Lastpage issue as \clearpage and then write the labels (by counting one page back). Normally this doesn't lead to a new page but a topskip of 0pt seems to confuse the output routine. latex sets topskip to a minimal value of 1 sp at begin document: `\ifdim\topskip<1sp\global\topskip 1sp\relax\fi`, but the source says as reason only `Since a value of exactly 0pt for \topskip causes \twocolumn[] to misbehave`.

Comment: try this code with and without `\topskip=0pt` `\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\topskip 0pt
\clearpage
\clearpage
\clearpage
\clearpage
\end{document}`

Comment: @touhami thanks, so I get 4 pages with `\topskip 0pt`, and an empty document without. Maybe the moral of the story is: this is why you should not put `\topskip` anywhere other than in the preamble.

Comment: no, `\topskip` should always be positive.